# AndroidのログにおけるNetworkController.WifiSignalControllerのactivityIn,activityOutの意味について

Tags: android

Androidにおけるログに関して、気になる点がありました。

```
10-17 12:37:54.412 896-896/? D/NetworkController.WifiSignalController: Change in state from: connected=true,enabled=true,level=4,inetCondition=1,iconGroup=IconGroup(Wi-Fi Icons),activityIn=false,activityOut=false,rssi=-52,lastModified=10-17 12:37:51,ssid="OWNER4838" to: connected=true,enabled=true,level=4,inetCondition=1,iconGroup=IconGroup(Wi-Fi Icons),activityIn=true,activityOut=true,rssi=-52,lastModified=10-17 12:37:51,ssid="OWNER4838"
```

ネットワーク接続のステータスが変更されているのだろうと思いますが、変わっている箇所は、activityIn および activityOut がfalseからtrueになっているところです。
このactivityIn および activityOut は何を意味するのでしょうか?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[WifiSignalController](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/cf053c1/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/statusbar/policy/WifiSignalController.java)のコードを見てみると以下のメソッドでステータスが変わっているのがわかります。

```
void setActivity(int wifiActivity) {
    mCurrentState.activityIn = wifiActivity == WifiManager.DATA_ACTIVITY_INOUT
            || wifiActivity == WifiManager.DATA_ACTIVITY_IN;
    mCurrentState.activityOut = wifiActivity == WifiManager.DATA_ACTIVITY_INOUT
            || wifiActivity == WifiManager.DATA_ACTIVITY_OUT;
    notifyListenersIfNecessary();
}
```

また、[WifiManagerのコード](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.0_r1/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.java)に定数の説明がコメントとしてかいてありました。

```
//Lowest bit indicates data reception and the second lowest
//bit indicates data transmitted
public static final int DATA_ACTIVITY_NONE         = 0x00;
public static final int DATA_ACTIVITY_IN           = 0x01;
public static final int DATA_ACTIVITY_OUT          = 0x02;
public static final int DATA_ACTIVITY_INOUT        = 0x03;
```

これから考えると、
データ受信時 : activityIn = true
データ送信時 : activityOut = true
なようです。

Comment: 明確な解答ありがとうございました。